# Leap motion libraries for d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, user-interaction, leap-motion

I am having my graduation project on data visualization, and I want to integrate the Leap Motion 3D Controller in the visualisation.

Where I could find resources to study from? And are there leap motion libraries for d3.js? I found about LMfP but it's for Processing.

Any suggestions? I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've made a demo that uses the controller with the force layout [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/lff/).

Comment: Thanks I will check it out.